# Is it possible that "bloom" affects grease-pencil object in 2.8 with EEVEE engine?

Tags: light, grease-pencil, 2d

So I am trying to do a animation where a TV emits light (bloom) and affects objects around it.
[image]
I already activated bloom and set that plane shader to "Emission" and it works with 3d Objects, as you can see in the right arm or even the mountains closer to the TV, where light stand out. But as you can see in the image the mountains behind the TV, that are grease pencil object, doesn't recognize the bloom.

All this I am doing it with EEVEE engine

Any ideas? Thank you people.